# Создание таблицы в мобильном приложении Azure

Tags: sql, база-данных, azure

Я только начал изучать Azure mobile apps, скачал сэмпл ToDoList, он заработал. Затем я захотел создать свою таблицу под названием Conference:

- Создал класс Conference.cs
- Сгенерировал ConferenceController.cs
- В контекстфайле добавил DbSet
- Опубликовал на сервер

Однако после этого всего таблица не создалась. Плюс я не очень понимаю как вести отладку этого приложения. Что я делаю не так?